# select the corresponding cell in the upper/lower triangle

Tags: r, matrix

Imagine we have something like:

```
mat <- matrix(rep(1,25), nrow = 5)
mat
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[3,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[4,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

If i select a cell in the matrix i.e. `mat[1]`, how can i systematically select the corresponding cell in the opposite triangle. i.e. `mat[25]`

for instance I could also select cell `mat[21]` then I would want `mat[5]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `i` be your `1` or `21`, you could do:

```
mat[length(mat) - i + 1]
```

or

```
rev(mat)[i]
```